# Creating active areas (hot spots) in image with JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, image, facebook, image-processing, dom-events

I want to build an application in which an image is presented. When one click area in the image then it can result with different outcomes, depends on the area in which he/she clicked. The outcome is always replacement of the image with another one-sometimes similar image with only small area if it different from the original picture.

My question is whether this can be done when the images are stored on external server so it would be smooth enough and wouldn't feel like the computer have to download the other picture (meaning that it would feel more like in game when action lead to immediate outcome).

Answer (score 1):

You could preload all images before starting your game.

Check this jquery solution for instance http://www.farinspace.com/jquery-image-preload-plugin/

This way you will get a smooth result on user interaction